# How to exclude the hidden directory from the result of find command

Tags: find, shell-script

I am searching for some directories in find command and if that directory is present then I need to take some action on it. But what is happening is: At some places though the main directories (for which I am searching) hidden `.svn` directories are present and they are populating as a result of `find`.

I dont want this .svn dir to be a part of find result.

Here is the find command which i am using :

```
find <search dir> -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d  -regex ".*/V[0-9]+/.*+/.*+")
```

Comment: Why did you not use `svn export` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
find some/dir \( -name .svn -prune \) -o \( ... \)
```

Comment: hey i am new to unix so not aware of many otions : do u mean something lke this :   find <dirname> -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type d \( -name .svn -prune \) -o \(.*/V[0-9]+/.*+ \)